# Feedback from your most recent submission : Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a web app that I'm trying to get in the Facebook App Center. After submitting it, I'm getting the following warning:

Feedback from your most recent submission:

> General
>   Your Open Graph story did not publish on any of the configured platforms. Update with more detailed usage instructions that indicate how to trigger and publish the action for all configured platforms.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Your instructions must not be in details.

You must explain clearly how a post is going to be published. You must be missing this and hence getting the warning.

Comment: I was published the app few days back, yesterday i saw the app submission status is "review" state in facebook but today i got above mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, so they have reviewed now and you have to fix this and then submit again

Comment: I am already searched regarding this issue over internet but I can not find any solution. please help me how to fix this issue.